# How to fix Samba read and write permissions for directories in an ext4 partition?

Tags: samba, ext4, cifs

I have two GNU/Linux distors installed on my laptop: ubuntu and archlinux. I have symlinked some diectories from archlinux's home directory to directories in the ubuntu home directoy. Those symlinked directories have write and read access on ubuntu CLI and GUI. But they cannot be browsed or opened if the ubuntu home directory is accessed as a samba share on windows machines. How can I make them writable for samba too? This is the etry for archlinux partition on ubuntu fstab file.

```
/dev/sda3       /media/arch   ext4    relatime    0       2
```

Answer (score 2):

edit your samba conf file(mostly /etc/samba/smb.conf and add the lines below:

```
follow symlinks = yes
wide symlinks = yes
unix extensions = no
```

Restart samba .

For more info visit this thread in Ubuntu forums:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=352016

Comment: It did not work for me.